# how to delete app and its settings from iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, settings, application-settings

I am testing app install on iPhone/iPad but I can do it only once because iOS remembers the settings, e.g. allow access to photos etc, and never clears them when I uninstall the app. Thus next time I install it it does not ask to allow access to photos etc.

Any way to completely delete app along with settings, besides resetting the device?

Comment: Clean building the folder might help you in that case. I am not sure though. Try once, I had permission for Push Notification re asked when I uninstalled and reinstalled the app.

Comment: did not help, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even after an App is deleted, the OS (iOS) remembers the permissions for a day in case the App is installed again. This is done for connivence sake when it comes to a common end user.

But it is a pain for developers.

The question gives me an impression that for testing purpose, you want the App to ask for permissions again, when you install the App again.

> This is how I do it. 1 --> Delete App.
>
> 2 --> Restart the device.
>
> 3--> Go to Date & Time settings in your device. And set the date to a
>   day ahead, preferably 2 days ahead to be on the safer side.
>
> 4 --> Restart the device.

Your App when installed now, should ask for permissions again.

Hope it helps

Comment: Nice workaround, it worked! It asks for the permissions again. Thanks a lot, b/c it is a pain, now I do not need to reset device, just the dates: 2days ahead, restart and then back.

Comment: THANK YOU. This is such a pain. you can just change the date, no need to restart

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on the kind of settings you are trying to reset, but typically the answer is no. Once the user answers that initial request for access a record is created and stored for user convenience. This record persists even if the app is deleted. Access to photos for example can after the initial request be administered in the app's settings in the Settings app. But upon revoking it the user is not asked for permission again. Instead a dialog comes up letting them know that the app has no access to photos, but they can allow future access in the app's settings. Other settings like privacy permissions are also administered in Settings, but have their own umbrella category. The pattern of initial request and future admin in Settings is pretty universal.

Comment: tx for the info. not what i was hoping for. oh well.