# iOS permissions cache after reinstall app

Tags: ios, iphone, permissions

while testing i noticed one interesting thing,I’m using Microphone ,location, camera Permissions in my app and asking for permissions from a user. When i install app for first time i sees default asking permissions pop up. And everything work fine. But  if i will remove app from phone and install it **again and again**  the permissions popups wont appear , but all working fine. if i visit app settings all permissions are granted already(which was given in last installation).

is this happen because of **cache issues**?. and how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: The answers [in this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840287/how-to-delete-app-and-its-settings-from-iphone-ipad) may help you out.  Basically the phone needs to be restarted.

Comment: have same issue after restarted my device. i tried this fix so many times.